# Efficient way to merge map with another map on partial matches of a field

Tags: java, algorithm

Say I have the following classes:

```
class PersonWithFirstName {
    String firstName;
}
class PersonWithFullName {
    String fullName; // note assume this is not delimited in any way
}
class PersonWithFirstNameAndFullName {
    String firstName;
    List fullNames; 
}
```

Now given a `Map<Integer, PersonWithFirstName>` and a `Map<Integer, PersonWithFullName>` where the key is the id (but the ids from the two maps are not coorelated), I want to write a function that returns `PersonWithFirstNameAndFullName` which for each `firstName` in `Map<String, PersonWithFirstName>`, finds any full names in the other map that begin with this firstName.

As an example:

```
Map<Integer, PersonWithFirstName> mapPersonsWithFirstName = new HashMap<>();
Map<Integer, PersonWithFulltName> mapPersonsWithFullName = new HashMap<>();

mapPersonsWithFirstName.set(1, new PersonWithFirstName("bob"));
mapPersonsWithFirstName.set(2, new PersonWithFirstName("alice"));
mapPersonsWithFullName.set(1, new PersonWithFullName("bobjohnson"));
mapPersonsWithFullName.set(2, new PersonWithFullName("bobjames"));



myFunction(mapPersonsWithFirstName, mapPersonsWithFullName)
/* should return
{
  1: {
    firstName: "bob"
    fullNames: ["bobjohnson", "bobjames"]
  },
  2: {
    firstName: "alice"
    fullNames: []
  }
}
*/
```

The only way I came up with is looping through the entryset of mapPersonsWithFirstName, and for each PersonWithFirstName doing another loop through mapPersonsWithFullName to find any PersonWithFullName.fullName that starts with PersonWithFirstName.firstName. This runs is exponential time, but I'm really thinking this can be solved in linear time. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you have to use a `Map<Interger, PersonWithFulltName`? One efficient way to do this would be to use a tree structure index on the name,  like `TreeMap<String, PersonWithFulltName>` with a `Comparator` grouping them by characters in order.

Comment: If you have a list of key (ids), you only need to iterate over that once. Getting an entry from both the maps based on the key is not expensive, O(1).

Comment: If the IDs from the maps are not correlated, then the problem is effectively how to "merge" two sets of strings into your desired map and nothing to do with merging maps as such?

Comment: One efficient way to do this is to create a Trie of your full names, which you can traverse/look up prefixes (your first names) and get all the completions from a given point. In practice, the suggestion of using a TreeMap (or indexing in some other way, e.g. index on first X characters) may be efficient enough for what you require.

Comment: Hi @BaptisteBeauvais, I'm seeing alot of suggestions for using TreeMap. Can you expand a little on what you mean by using a Comparator to group them by characters in order?

Comment: @MattC. I can do that, do you understand how tree-based data structure works? Like a binary tree for example.

Comment: @BaptisteBeauvais yes I understand binary trees (right is greater than, left is less than)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `TreeSet` for ordering all your names and then just get desired subsequences (using `tailSet` and `headSet` methods):

```java
    private static List<PersonWithFirstNameAndFullName> myFunction(List<String> firstNames, List<String> fullNames) {
        List<PersonWithFirstNameAndFullName> res = new ArrayList<>();
        firstNames.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());
        NavigableSet<String> allNames = Stream.concat(firstNames.stream(), fullNames.stream()).collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
        for (String firstName : firstNames) {
            final SortedSet<String> tail = allNames.tailSet(firstName, false);
            allNames = new TreeSet<>(allNames.headSet(firstName));
            res.add(new PersonWithFirstNameAndFullName(firstName, new ArrayList<>(tail)));
        }
        return res;
    }
```

If the code above doesn't quite meet your requirements, you can change it.
But, in general, the main idea is to use `TreeSet` or `TreeMap`.

*Update (to match the signature of your methods):*

```java
    public static List<PersonWithFirstNameAndFullName> myFunction(Map<Integer, PersonWithFirstName> mapPersonsWithFirstName, Map<Integer, PersonWithFullName> mapPersonsWithFullName) {
        return myFunction(mapPersonsWithFirstName.values().stream().map(PersonWithFirstName::getFirstName).collect(Collectors.toList()),
                mapPersonsWithFullName.values().stream().map(PersonWithFullName::getFullName).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this way It is not exponential anymore:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<Integer, PersonWithFirstName> firstNames = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, PersonWithFullName> fullNames = new HashMap<>();

    firstNames.put(1, new PersonWithFirstName("bob"));
    firstNames.put(2, new PersonWithFirstName("alice"));
    firstNames.put(3, new PersonWithFirstName("test1"));
    firstNames.put(4, new PersonWithFirstName("test2"));
    firstNames.put(5, new PersonWithFirstName("test3"));
    fullNames.put(1, new PersonWithFullName("bobjohnson"));
    fullNames.put(2, new PersonWithFullName("bobjames"));
    fullNames.put(3, new PersonWithFullName("test1aaaa"));
    fullNames.put(4, new PersonWithFullName("aliceSurname"));

    Map<String, Set<String>> firstToFull = new HashMap<>();

    List<String> firstNamesSorted = firstNames.values().stream().map(it -> it.firstName).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<String> fullNamesSorted = fullNames.values().stream().map(it -> it.fullName).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());

    int indexFirstName = 0;
    int indexFullName = 0;
    while (indexFirstName < firstNamesSorted.size() && indexFullName < fullNamesSorted.size()) {
        String firstName = firstNamesSorted.get(indexFirstName);
        String fullName = fullNamesSorted.get(indexFullName);
        if (fullName.startsWith(firstName)) {
            firstToFull.computeIfAbsent(firstName, n -> new HashSet<>())
                    .add(fullName);
            indexFullName++;
        } else {
            if(compare(firstName, fullName) == 1) {
                indexFullName++;
            } else {
                indexFirstName++;
            }
        }
    }

    int firstNamesSize = firstNamesSorted.size();
    int i = 0;
    while (firstToFull.size() < firstNamesSize) {
       String name = firstNamesSorted.get(i);
       firstToFull.computeIfAbsent(name, n -> new HashSet<>());
       i++;
    }
    
    System.out.println(firstToFull);

}

private static int compare(String firstName, String fullName) {
    String substring = fullName.substring(0, firstName.length());
    return firstName.compareTo(substring);
}
```